# Is there any proof of the criterion of determining maximal ideal in a commutative ring with unity by Third Isomorphism Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> **Theorem.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity $1$ and $M$ is an ideal of $R$. Show that $M$ is maximal iff $\dfrac{R}{M}$ is a field.

In the proof of this theorem the methods so far I have seen are some variant of Theorem 3.4.2 of [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_772nrrTMAhXF1I4KHVYABA8QFghFMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.nuigalway.ie%2FMA416%2Fsection3-4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFb-bORT_-jq10vp63gcNBigl-fuQ) or an argument similar to that sketched [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkl5zLsrTMAhVQcI4KHZNYC2MQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Fmathematics%2F18-703-modern-algebra-spring-2013%2Flecture-notes%2FMIT18_703S13_pra_l_18.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEAWA5zgtmL8maNSc7qWPUwIZokvQ) in the proof of Theorem 18.8.

My question is,

> Is there any proof of the above theorem using the Third Isomorphism Theorem?

Comment: At least one direction seems to easily follow from the 3rd Iso theorem: if $R/M$ is a field, then since a field has no nontrivial ideals, the isomorphism theorem says there can be no ideal strictly between $M$ and $R$, and so $M$ is maximal.

Comment: Doesn't your second link exactly use the Third Isomorphism Theorem?

Comment: @Slade: Where does it use that?